# How to color-balance false-composites of pan-sharpened Landsat images in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, landsat

Whenever I try to pan-sharpen composites of some Landsat images in GRASS using `i.pansharpen`, `i.fusion.brovey` or the IHS sharpening method, the output will have some or all of the following characteristics:

- the composite color is in a different hue compared to the un-sharpened composite
- the brightness level is messed up
- the entire composite went all-white/all-black (when using images pre-processed to top-of-atmosphere reflectance or surface reflectance corrections in `i.landsat.toar`)

I've also tried **all** of the following; but the colors/brightness remained the same or turned even worse:

- Applied `i.landsat.rgb`, before-and-after the pan-sharpening process
- Played with the `-f` or `-p` flag in `i.landsat.rgb`
- Tried `r.colors` to edit the color table to grey/grey255/grey.eq
- Tried `i.pansharpen` using all Brovey/IHS/PCA methods
- Played with the `-l` flag in `i.pansharpen` to rebalance the blue-channel

The [GRASS GIS manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/html70_user/) did explained on how to perform pan-sharpening and color-balancing, but I can't figure out how to combine both processes in a concurrent workflow. I suspected that this is due to my poor understanding of color-tables, color-histogram, etc. in GRASS..

So, can someone explain to me - **how do you tackle color-balancing problems when dealing with Landsat images after image-processing in GRASS?** Can you share with me your favorite workflow/methods?

Many thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Overview

One working approach inside GRASS-GIS version 7 to get an acceptable color-balanced composite image after Pan-sharpening is

1. check if input data are 8-bit ranging inside [0, 255]
2. if the data are inside [0, 255] proceed then to pan-sharpening (`i.pansharpen`)
3. if the data are not inside [0, 255], rescale them to this range (`r.rescale`)
4. pan-sharpen with any of the featured methods (Brovey, IHS, PCA)
5. color-balance automatically by using the `i.landsat.rgb` module or manually adjusting the color tables of the bands of interest

### Details and example instructions

**[Pan-Sharpening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansharpened_image) / [Fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_fusion)**

[GRASS 7](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/) holds a dedicated pan-sharpening module, [`i.pansharpen`](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/i.pansharpen.html) which features three techniques for sharpening, namely the [Brovey transformation](http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Brovey_Transformation), the classical IHS method and one that is based on [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

`i.pansharpen` works fine with 8-bit raster maps as an input. If the data to be processed are out of this range, that is out of `[0, 255]`, they can be rescaled to fit into this range by using GRASS' [`r.rescale`](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.rescale.html) module.

Given a set of 11-bit spectral bands (for example Blue, Green, Red, NIR and Pan) ranging between `[0, 2047]`, querying the Blue band for example would return

```
r.info Blue_DNs -r
min=0
max=2047
```

Rescaling the Blue band to range between `[0, 255]`

```
r.rescale in=Blue_DNs out=Blue_DNs_255 from=0,2047 to=0,255
```

The same step applies to both the rest of the multi-spectral bands and the Panchromatic band of interest.

As usual when working with GRASS, it is required to set the region of interest, i.e. [`g.region`](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/g.region.html)`rast=Blue_DNs_255` to match the extent of the band(s) or else. The resolution itself is taken care in this particular case by the module and the resulting pan-sharpened raster maps will be of the same high(er) resolution as the Panchromatic band.

An example command for an IHS-based Pan-Sharpening action might look like

```
i.pansharpen pan=Pan_DNs_255 ms1=Blue_DNs_255 ms2=Green_DNs_255 ms3=Red_DNs_255 output=sharptest255 sharpen=ihs
```

**Color Balancing**

After the process completion, the module outputs

```
...
The following pan-sharpened output maps have been generated:
sharptest255_red
sharptest255_green
sharptest255_blue

To visualize output, run: g.region -p rast=sharptest255.red
d.rgb r=sharptest255_red g=sharptest255_green b=sharptest255_blue
```

Normally it should be enough to re-balance the colors after the pan-sharpening by using for example the [i.landsat.rgb](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/i.landsat.rgb.html) module or manual adjustment of each of the three bands that would compose an RGB image.

**Screenshots**

...*to be added*

Comment: I knew there must be a better way! Now I can freely use the i.sharpen module. Thanks for pointing out the r.rescale module. Awesome work Nikos!

Comment: Haziq, I am not sure if and how much of the "fine" details are lost when converting 11-bit data sets to 8-bit. QuickBird imagery, for example, is an 11-bit sensor. They are available in both 8-bit and 16-bit formats. It is up to the user to decide what to do.  It would certainly be nice for `i.pansharpen` to handle all kinds of formats.  Please have a look at a related "ticket": [Ticket #2048: i.pansharpen limited to 8-bit imagery](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass./ticket/2048). On the other hand, I simply might not understand stuff and, thus, not able to use i.pansharpen properly... ?

Answer (score 7):

I've searched high-and-low, and I think I've discovered the root of my problems. I believe I got the solution for them now - but it's a little bit messy. I'm sure there are better ways to solve them. Do share if you know an easier way!

**ROOTS OF PROBLEMS:**

1. **The output of** `i.landsat.toar` **is in floating point**. I've realized that when I use floating point rasters in any pan-sharpening method, the colors will mess-up. Those algorithm somehow preferred rasters in the original integer form.
2. **Pan-sharpening modules such as** `i.pansharpen` **and** `i.fusion.brovey` **modules will mess-up the colors**. I haven't quite grasp the algorithms that they used in those modules - but somehow the color-tables will be affected, and ruining the resulting pan-sharpened images.

**SOLUTION:**

1. **Convert output from** `i.landsat.toar` **from float to int, using** `r.recode`.
2. **Use the rasters as inputs in IHS pan-sharpening method** (`i.rgb.his` and `i.his.rgb`). I keep away from using `i.pansharpen` and `i.fusion.brovey`.

**THE WORKFLOW:**

1. **Use** `r.info` **with the** `-r` **flag to get the DN min and max values** of each raster bands which have been processed with `i.landsat.toar`. For example:

   ```
   > r.info -r BAND1
   min=0.01
   max=0.370064120902708
   ```

   As we can see, the values is between 0-1, which are pretty different than the original ones (which are between 0-255). That explains why the output from pan-sharpening turned out blank, because the used range-of-value is very low (below 1).
2. **Convert that raster band using** `r.recode`. Use the min and max values obtained from step 1 to convert into a new range of 0-255. An example code snippet:

   ```
   r.recode input=BAND1 output=NEWBAND1 rules=- << EOF
   0.01:0.370064120902708:0:255
   EOF
   ```

   We can check the new converted values with `r.info`:

   ```
   > r.info -r NEWBAND1
   min=1
   max=254
   ```

   Values are in 0-255: now it's usable for pan-sharpening process.
3. **Apply gray-scale color table to the converted band with** `r.colors`.

   ```
   r.colors NEWBAND1 color=grey
   ```

   So far, I get the best results using the grey color table - the pan-sharpened composites matched closely with the original composites. The other alternatives are to equalize grey color table with `color=grey.eq` or using the `-e` flag with `color=grey`. Or we can use the `i.landsat.rgb` module instead of `r.colors`..
4. **Repeat step 1-3** with other raster bands that we intend to be use as composites, **including the pan raster** (band 8). Use of scripts would be much appreciated here.
5. **Then use the processed rasters as inputs in IHS pan-sharpening method**. For example, when making the composite of band 7,4,2:

   ```
   i.rgb.his r=NEWBAND7 g=NEWBAND4 b=NEWBAND2 hue=HUE int=INT sat=SAT
   ```

   This will output 3 layers: a hue layer `HUE`, an intensity layer `INT`, and also a saturation layer `SAT`. We will then replace the intensity layer `INT` with the pan raster band `NEWBAND8` in `i.his.rgb`:

   ```
   i.his.rgb hue=HUE sat=SAT int=NEWBAND8 r=COMP742_red g=COMP742_green b=COMP742_blue
   ```

   Resulting red channels of **COMP742_red**, **COMP742_green**, **COMP742_blue** can then be combined using `d.rgb` or `r.composite`..

**SAMPLE BEFORE & AFTER:**

Before pan-sharpening:

[image: Before]

After pan-sharpening:

[image: After]

**Maybe it's hard to tell the sharpening differences**, when viewing from such small images. But what's important is the color of the pan-sharpened image matched the composite from the original. Mission accomplished!

**OTHER NOTES:**

- **Don't** `r.recode` **the thermal bands (band 6)**. `i.landsat.toar` output these thermal bands in Kelvin temperature values (nothing to do with DN values). Keep the `r.recode` routine on the normal multi-spectral and pan bands (bands 1-5,7,8).
- **If we never even use** `i.landsat.toar`, **but the resulting composites look really wrong**, it's usually because of mismatching of color-tables before and after pan-sharpening process. I applied `r.colors RASTER color=grey` to the original raster bands before pan-sharpening, and to the resulting channels after pan-sharpening to ensure close-matching of colors.
- **A usual case of the wrong-color composite problem**: the original raster bands are in `color=grey255`, the output of `i.landsat.rgb` is in `color=grey.eq`. No wonder they both look different!
- **Processing landsat images for use could really be a time-taxing activity**. Better have something to do when waiting for it all to process, or at least have some ludicrous amount of coffee and good music while you're at it ;)

Hope this would benefit someone : took me days to find what's wrong..

Comment: Thanks for your research and efforts, I also had this problem in new GRASS 7 from svn. Now the colours of pansharpened image is OK. =)

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention which version of GRASS I'm running - thanks @VladimirNaumov for reminding! I am using GRASS 7svn; should have realized that this issue could be something that doesn't happen across all versions of GRASS (I haven't tried other versions)..

Comment: Back to this: you can convert floating point raster maps to integer raster maps by using `r.mapcalc` along with its integrated `int()` function. I think `r.recode` is not meant to be used in the context of your application.

Comment: I think the overall "problem" regarding `i.pansharpen` is that it expects 8-bit raster maps as input, i.e. the input values should range from 0 to 255.

Comment: Also, note that `i.pansharpen` is in grass7_trunk only. That is the development version... :-)

Comment: Your post helped me a lot, thank you! In my case, after recoding the files created with `i.landsat.toar` (carefully using `g.region raster=<panchromatic_toar>` before recoding the panchormatic toar corrected band, to avoid losing resolution), i just used i.pansharpen and it worked OK. GRASS version 7.0.3 (64 bit).

Comment: I made a little script to document my process (warning: didn't test it yet): https://github.com/jumanbar/misc/blob/master/GRASS/grass_pansharpen_example.sh