# How to pansharpen LANDSAT 8 in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, landsat, color, pansharpening, landsat-8

Having used QGIS for quite some time for mapping, I was 'forced' to dig into GRASS as pansharpening is not directly executable in QGIS. After understanding more or less the structure, I did some trials with i.fusion.brovey. I was able to generate the rasters with 15m resolution, but when loading into QGIS I can not achieve/recuperate the nice colour contrast  as is present in the original 30m rasters.

In an [earlier post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39174/how-to-color-balance-false-composites-of-pan-sharpened-landsat-images-in-grass) someone confirmed that and proposed to use another function for landsat: 'i.his.rgb' (after using i.landsat.toar, which I don't use). He starts to convert min/max to 1-255 before using i.his.rgb...My original rasters have a range of 0-65535. It did not work out for me...

I quit after some days of struggling to just perform a pansharp, I feel stuck... Why should just applying i.pansharp not work for Landsat as suggested by others? Can someone suggest a more straightforward workflow to execute pansharpening of Landsat 8 images? Looking forward to some advice, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Michal and Markus. Finally I was able to do the pansharpening with the indicated function brov. Once performed in GRASS, I exported the RGB rasters to gdal GTiff with as data type Uint16. Markus, I have been downloading and using several Landsat 8 images (tiff of each of the  11 bands), obtaining nice visual results, both in natural/false color. To my knowledge, the original landsat tiffs come as Uint16 with values ranging from 0 to 65535 (or am I missing something?)...Thanks for the GRASS LANDSAT link...

Comment: Yes, Landsat 8 images are stored as Uint16 types.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at  [i.landsat.rgb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OshFh.jpg) - Performs auto-balancing of colors for LANDSAT images, probably before running the pansharpening. You may also consider to convert the digital numbers of the individual channels to top-of-atmosphere radiance or reflectance with [i.landsat.toar](http://blog.neteler.org/processing-landsat-8-data-in-grass-gis-7-rgb-composites-and-pan-sharpening/). See also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LANDSAT

BTW: having a range of 0-65535 for original LANDSAT data is odd since they are delivered as 8 bit channels (0-255). So check your input data first.

**Update: 10/2013**

For a simplified procedure with current GRASS GIS 7, see the page [image][Processing Landsat 8 data in GRASS GIS 7: RGB composites and pan sharpening](http://blog.neteler.org/processing-landsat-8-data-in-grass-gis-7-rgb-composites-and-pan-sharpening/)

Comment: I originally came across that article you're linking from neteler.org, but the instructions didn't work at all (because of the floating point format of rasters generated with `i.landsat.toar`, so I ended up following advice from here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/39239/9857

Comment: Note that that advice was given many years ago and does not reflect latest GRASS GIS code. BTW: a really great pansharpening module is the new addon: i.fusion.hpf - Fusing high resolution Panchromatic and low resolution Multi-Spectral data based on the High-Pass Filter Addition technique, see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/i.fusion.hpf.html

Answer (score 3):

Pan-sharpening FIHS or Brovery Transform is quite simple if you follow the formulae from an article such as this: http://www.sensorsportal.com/HTML/DIGEST/august_2014/Vol_177/P_RP_0183.pdf

Assuming you are using GRASS GIS and pansharpening Landsat 8.

Set your region using the pan 8 tif - important to have resolution 15m which will be set if you do this.

For Brovery without weights enter this into Map Calculator for blue, green and red respectively:

band8 / (band2+band3+band4) / 3 * band2

band8 / (band2+band3+band4) / 3 * band3

band8 / (band2+band3+band4) / 3 * band4

Run r.colors for each of the above outputs and set histogram equalisation and color table to grey.

Run r.composite, select the appropriate bands (red=4,green=3,blue=2)

Check out image.

Obviously this process could be done with more consideration for atmospheric correction, color stretch and band weights as discussed in above article.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [Monteverdi](http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBooksu27.html) to perform pansharpening. This tool can consume regular GeoTIFFs as input (however, separate multispectral bands have to be merged into one multiband raster), and performs reasonably well.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this issue I found a simple solution that lets you pan-sharpen in QGIS (2.18.21 is my version) using SCP. The update to SCP incorporating this method is described here https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2015/07/major-update-semi-automatic-44.html.

This is easy to do and it ran like a charm! I checked the final output and the pixels measure at 15 m in resolution - matching the panchromatic 8 band. If anyone is curious - it uses the Brovey Transform method as described in the manual (see https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/semiautomaticclassificationmanual/latest/semiautomaticclassificationmanual.pdf).

[image: Step 1 for SCP pansharpen tool]
[image: Step 3-4 for SCP pansharpen]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site Janos. Ideally answers such as yours should have a description as to why they are good methods. ..

For pansharpening of Landsat 8 pictures the easier method the http://www.geosage.com/highview/download.html.   My advise, try it.
Only one click....[image: Spectraltransformer]

Answer (score -2):

For pansharpenig I used GUI spectral transformer for Landsat 8 pictures[image] http://www.geosage.com/highview/download.html    Very good.
BR
Janos

Comment: Welcome to the site Janos.  Ideally answers such as yours should have a description as to why they are good methods.  Link only answers tend to become defunct if the link goes away.