# Using Landsat 8 for quantitative analysis - what DNs does GRASS require?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, landsat

Hoping someone can short circuit a lot of exploration

Landsat 8 values are stored as unint16 since the sensors work on a range 0 to 4096 whereas the L7+TM was 8 bit and had a digital number range 0 to 255. 
[USGS link](http://landsat.usgs.gov/L8_12_bit.php)

Looking at the unprocessed bands in QGIS, the value tool reports values of ~8000 for band 3, whereas GRASS reports values of ~0.19 . For the same bands in L7+TM band 3 values are ~30

Understandably, the output from my old workflow in GRASS is giving nonsense. i.landsat.toar does read L8 but with the funny numbers I don't expect it is on the right track.

The end use is NDVI, I don't expect a pansharpening workflow to be the same.

Any tips on a new workflow?

Comment: I guess this question touches on the same issues, but to reclass would be experimenting, hoping someone has some detailed knowledge  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39174/how-to-color-balance-false-composites-of-pan-sharpened-landsat-images-in-grass?rq=1

Comment: It's clear that TOAR reads the dn as less than 1, the following from the verbose output of the module  `BAND 1  (code 1)
   calibrated digital number (DN): 0.0 to 0.0
   calibration constants (L): -0.000 to 0.000
   at-surface radiance = 0.00000000 * DN + -0.000
   mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance (ESUN): -0.000
   at-surface reflectance = radiance / 0.00000
   the darkness DN with a least 1000 pixels is 1
   the DN mode is 0`

Answer (score 1):

The [i.landsat.toar](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/i.landsat.toar.html) version included in Grass7 supports the new Landsat8 OLI/TIRS sensor and worked flawless in my tries. One thing you have to be careful is that Landsat 8 has different band designations. So band 3 on Landsat 7 is equivalent to band 4 on Landsat 8.

Comment: On Win or Nix computer?  ta

Comment: Sidenote: Also the new GRASS GIS 6.4.3 supports Landsat 8: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/i.landsat.toar.html