# Pansharpening Landsat 8 tiles in Grass 7

Tags: grass-gis, landsat-8, pansharpening

I am trying to get some nice looking RGB images for visualization purposes, mainly using as background maps, from the Landsat 8 archive. I was following the tutorial provided by Markus Neteler at 
   http://courses.neteler.org/processing-landsat8-data-in-grass-gis-7/ and    http://courses.neteler.org/processing-landsat-8-data-in-grass-gis-7-rgb-composites-and-pan-sharpening/ using WinGRASS-7.0.0.1.

The steps I used so far

```
Import the tiles for scene LC81740382014220LGN00 using r.in.gdal
```

Set the computational region using

```
g.region rast=LC81740382014220LGN00_B1
```

Convert the digital number data (DN) to reflectance

```
i.landsat.toar input=LC81740382014220LGN00_B output=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl metfile=D:\Landsat\LC81740382014220LGN00_MTL.txt
```

Balance the colors

```
 i.colors.enhance red=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl4@LandsatImport green=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl3@LandsatImport blue=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl2@LandsatImport
```

Display

```
d.rgb red=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl4 green=red=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl3 blue=red=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl2
```

which gives already a nice looking composite. But further on

```
i.pansharpen red=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl4@LandsatImport green=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl3@LandsatImport blue=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl2@LandsatImport pan=LC81740382014220LGN00_refl8@LandsatImport output=LC81740382014220LGN00_copy_brovey method=brovey
```

and then again

```
d.rgb red=LC81740382014220LGN00_brovey_red green=LC81740382014220LGN00_brovey_green blue=LC81740382014220LGN00_brovey_blue
```

results in reddisch rgb composite [image]

balancing the colors

```
i.colors.enhance red=LC81740382014220LGN00_brovey_red@LandsatImport green=LC81740382014220LGN00_brovey_green@LandsatImport blue=LC81740382014220LGN00_brovey_blue@LandsatImport
```

results in [image]

Any ideas where something went wrong?

In addition: I also tried installing the i.fusion.hp extension but failed. My Grass installation is located in C:\grass70 and i extracted the archive to C:\i.fusion.hpf-master . After switching to the extension folder running

```
make MODULE_TOPDIR=$GISBASE
Makefile:7: ISBASE/include/Make/Script.make: No such file or directory
Makefile:8: ISBASE/include/Make/Python.make: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target
`ISBASE/include/Make/Python.make'.  Stop.
```

Where does the G in GISBASE go?

Comment: In order to compile an add-on, you need to have GRASS GIS' source code. Please read the respective [README](https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/README) file. I have no access to a Windows machine. Someone, though, has installed and used `i.fusion.hpf` under Windows, as can be seen in this ["issue"](https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/i.fusion.hpf/issues/6) discussion.

Comment: As for the `i.pansharpen` process, please post the range of raster values just before calling `i.pansharpen`, for example, what does `r.info -r LC81740382014220LGN00_refl4` report?  Check also http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/67319/5256.