# Can QGIS do color transformation from RGB to IHS (Intensity,Hue,Saturation)?

Tags: qgis, color

I need to transform RGB map to IHS is that feature available in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Then please [edit] your question to clarify your research efforts.

Comment: Google Books search indicates this is available via GRASS for QGIS. `i.rgb.his`.  I don't know enough of QGIS right now to expand into a full answer.   
 Book is [QGIS and Generic Tools by Nicolas Baghdadi, Clément Mallet, Mehrez Zribi](https://books.google.com/books?id=vppNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=transform+intensity+hue+saturation+in+qgis&source=bl&ots=4ndKGRpNO1&sig=xS1RO8uEVYXQapr8xECcJxdMT08&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi079DGiv3eAhXl54MKHQZXCDsQ6AEwDHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=transform%20intensity%20hue%20saturation%20in%20qgis&f=false)

Comment: Another resource: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/i.rgb.his.html

Answer (score 1):

The tool to complete this in QGIS is part of a plugin called GRASS.

`i.rgb.his`

Some resources for learning about this tool and GRASS:

[QGIS and Generic Tools by Nicolas Baghdadi, Clément Mallet, Mehrez Zribi](https://books.google.com/books?id=vppNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=transform+intensity+hue+saturation+in+qgis&source=bl&ots=4ndKGRpNO1&sig=xS1RO8uEVYXQapr8xECcJxdMT08&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi079DGiv3eAhXl54MKHQZXCDsQ6AEwDHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=transform%20intensity%20hue%20saturation%20in%20qgis&f=false)

[QGIS 2.8 Documention -- link goes directly to GRASS setup section](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/grass/grass_setup.html)

[How to color-balance false-composites of pan-sharpened Landsat images in GRASS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39174)

Comment: when I use i.rgb.his I get this error                   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 415, in processAlgorithm
Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)

Comment: Please add a new question outlining what you've tried, including the a code snippet and the error message.  As we have a one question per post format, if the answer above solved your initial question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [WhiteboxTools](https://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/WhiteboxTools/index.html) plugin for QGIS ([Whitebox for Processing](https://plugins.bruy.me/processing-whitebox.html)) offers RGB => IHS (`RgbToIhs` tool) and IHS => RGB (`IhsToRgb` tool) transformation:

[image]

The tool takes three input images (corresponding to red, green, and blue) and outputs three images (corresponding to intensity, hue, and saturation). If your input image is single RGB colour-composite just use the `SplitColourComposite` tool to create the three inputs.